# Ns biding abording issue only on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in the Firefox browser that I cannot solve. So the problem is the following: I have a function that I use to collect data when a page receives a refresh

```
const eventName = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";
        
this.window.addEventListener(eventName, async () => {
  await this.saveAction(this.typeOfActions.unknown);
  await this.saveActionMetaData();
});
saveAction = async (
        type, 
        filters = null, 
        searchTerm = "",
        url = null
        ) => {
        await this.http.post(`${this.collectorApi}${this.endpoints.action}`, {
            target: url ? url : this.currentUrl,
            duration: Math.round((this.timeSpentOnPage / 1000) * 100) / 100 || 0,
            idle_time: isNaN(this.idleTime) ? 0 : Math.round((this.idleTime / 1000) * 100) / 100,
            type: type,
            filters: ! filters ? {} : filters,
            session_id: this.#getSessionId(),
            searched_term: searchTerm
        });
    }
saveActionMetaData = async () => {
        await this.http.post(`${this.collectorApi}${this.endpoints.actionMetaData}`, {
            filters: [],
            data: {},
            idle_time: Math.round((this.timeSpentOnPage / 1000) * 100) / 100 || 0,
            duration: isNaN(this.idleTime) ? 0 : Math.round((this.idleTime / 1000) * 100) / 100,
            action_url: this.currentUrl,
            search_terms: [],
            session_id: this.#getSessionId()
        });
    }

post = async (
        endpoint, 
        data
    ) => {
        try {
            return await (await fetch(endpoint, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: this.headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })).json();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out where the error is. I simply get that error only on Firefox.

Comment: What is "Ns biding abording"?